# How much do bullets 'fall off' in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I have been playing PUBG for a while, from Counter-Strike admittedly, and I am having a hard time adjusting to projectile over hitscan. How much should I adjust when shooting at someone in PUGB? How do I determine how far they are away for certain scopes that have the lines? I see some streamers using Q/E when shooting, and they shoot on an angle. Is this to help lead the bullets when people are running?

I feel like I have my cursor on the players head and miss a ton or am not getting headshots. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah, when you refer to "zeroing" is that the distance the scope is showing? The default seems to be 100m?

Comment: Thank you for the help! Do you have any tips for which zeroing is the most useful? I feel like I will have trouble estimating distance, I know that 1 square = 100m, but not sure how to estimate when looking at someone through a scope.

Comment: I will have to look into the custom matches because it is something I really need. My games go on for a long time, but I don't feel like I am getting any better. I wish there was a better way to practice, or a way to see where people drop. Sometimes I will drop in a spot I think will be heavily populated, but empty. How do you decide where to drop? Does it depend on the plans angle?

Comment: Usually yes - that's the nature of the game though.  The only thing you can really do to see where people land is while you are parachuting (not free falling) rotate your camera around and see if anyone else is parachuting nearby.  That's what I do.  Don't rotate the camera as you are free falling as you will change the direction of where you are going.

Comment: Thanks for the advice man, if you toss some stuff you mentioned here in the comments as an answer I will gladly pick yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can help do to compensate for bullet drop is adjust your zeroing.  This down by pressing <kbd>Page Up</kbd> to increase it, or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to decrease it by default.  You can change the key mappings in the settings.  Note that you can only see how far your zero distance is when you are scoped in (first person perspective).

If you are exactly 100 meters away from something, and your zeroing is set to 100m, your bullet should hit exactly where your cross hair is. If you are zeroing for 300 meters and your are exactly 300 meters away, your bullet should (again) hit exactly at the cross hair.  If you don't want to use zeroing, you'll have to aim above the target you are trying to hit to compensate for drop.  Both methods will likely result in trial and error, unless you are very good at estimating distance.  On the flip side, if you are using zeroing, and you are compensating for too long of a distance (say 500 meters but your target is really at like 450 meters), you'll have to aim slightly below them instead.

You really just have to get a feel for the bullet drop in the game. <s>I think you can setup a custom match where you could at least practice.</s> As far I'm aware, judgement is the only way to figure out how far you are from a target.

Comment: Unless they recently added the feature, I don't believe it is possible for just anyone to create a custom PUBG match. The ability to create game servers is only provided to certain groups chosen by Bluehole.

Comment: @Malco I believe you right actually. I thought I saw an option to make your own, but I checked the other day and there doesn't appear to be a way.  I edited my answer.

Comment: @ TimmyJim it is rather annoying that you can't test stuff out outside of games. Hopefully they will add the ability to create and host custom games eventually or at very least a gun range style testing area.

Comment: @TimmyJim you can tell how far away you are from a target with the map. Each white line is 100m apart.

Comment: @TBear I thought I mentioned that but it looks like I didn't. I find that hard to estimate with anyway though since the map doesn't point out locations of other players besides yourself and teammates.

Comment: @TimmyJim it's not perfect but that is the main reference for distance. If you are set up with a sniper, you would do well to look at your map and note how far away the landmarks are around you